# Trying to make sense of how to use method in a little different use case

Tags: c#, async-await, task, c#-5.0

I have a method with following signature,

```
private async Task<SomeClass> SomeMethod(string param)
```

Somewhere in code,I am an array of task, I am able to use following code without any issue where I am adding the result of SomeMethod into array of task.

```
Task<SomeClass>[] tasks = new Task<SomeClass>[100];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
        tasks[i] = SomeMethod(param);
}
```

However in another use case,  I want to await on this method and getting results back I may or may not add this into tasks array. So within the the loop, I have code as follows.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
Task<SomeClass> result = await SomeMethod(param);
// if get back something useful then set tasks[i] to this task
}
```

Problem is that with this code, I am getting following compilation error.

> Error 7   Cannot implicitly convert type 'SomeClass' to
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'

Suggestions?

Comment: i'm not seeing `SomeClass` being assigned to a task. can you provide a more complete reproducible example?

Comment: @DanielA.White This is section from a large code, so I am trying to simplify code as much as possible. Do you want to see how its returned from SomeMthod?

Comment: never mind - you shouldn't need to call assign to a task when using `await`.

Comment: then how can I add it into tasks array?

Comment: @johnsmith Why do you need the `Task` when you know that they'll all have already completed successfully?  Are you getting anything out of the tasks besides the result?

Comment: what is the intent of the array?

Comment: Actually you are right. I need to think through this again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    Task<SomeClass> task = SomeMethod(param);
    await task;

    // if get back something useful then set tasks[i] to this task
    task[i] = task;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public void Test()
    {
        Task<SomeClass>[] tasks = new Task<SomeClass>[100];
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            tasks[i] = SomeMethod(string.Empty);
        }
    }

    private async Task<SomeClass> SomeMethod(object param)
    {
        return await Task.FromResult<SomeClass>(new SomeClass());
    }
```

Comment: The problem is that with that how can I add it into Task<SomeClass>[] tasks?

Comment: This is identical to the OP's first snippet.